# How to rearrange columns of dataframe using variables as column index

Tags: r

I am trying to rearrange columns of a data frame by using variables as column indices rather than column names or hard coded column positions but am not able to do so.

For example, if I have a data frame called 'test' with 12 rows and 7 columns like so :-

> [image: Blockquote]

The values in the data frame are just random numbers. The structure of the data frame is like so :-

```
str(allmodifiedwthhistdatareccountdf)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  12 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ wthmsngfixedupdf: int  44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 ...
 $ wthlgddf        : int  44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 ...
 $ wthlgdrcncydf   : int  44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 ...
 $ landrmwdf       : int  44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 ...
 $ trenddf         : int  44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 ...
 $ excldatesdf     : int  44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 44640 ...
 $ FcstID          : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Please ignore the values shown in the structure output as they are some values put in for convenience.

I want to have the FcstID column as the first column. I am doing this but its not working :-

```
test[, c(ncol(test), 1:(ncol(test) - 1))]
```

Comes up with something weird.

But this seems to work :-

```
test[, c(7, 1:6)]
```

but this doesn't

```
test[c(7, 1:6)]
```

Any suggestions? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If `test[, c(7, 1:6)]` works I do not understand what do you want? That's a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the structure it seems you have a `data.table`. To reorder columns by number use `setcolorder`.

See this example -

```
library(data.table)
df <- mtcars[1:7, 1:7]
setDT(df)  
df

#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec
#1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46
#2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02
#3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61
#4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44
#5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02
#6: 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22
#7: 14.3   8  360 245 3.21 3.570 15.84

setcolorder(df, c(ncol(df), 1:(ncol(df) - 1)))
df
#    qsec  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt
#1: 16.46 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620
#2: 17.02 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875
#3: 18.61 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320
#4: 19.44 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215
#5: 17.02 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440
#6: 20.22 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460
#7: 15.84 14.3   8  360 245 3.21 3.570
```

Comment: <- That worked beautifully. Thanks. However, why does the same not work with the data frame syntax? Also, why does it work on data frames with hard coded column indices?

Comment: Iago <- I wanted variable based answer not hard coded column indices.

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal Because dataframe and datatables are different. Not everything which works on dataframes will work on data table and vice versa. So we need to use the syntax according to the type which we have.

Comment: Ronak<- Understand that but if you look at the definition under the 'str' command, it does say classes of 'data.table' and 'data.frame'. So shouldn't it work for both. This is just out of interest as the solution provided by you works for me.

Comment: That is how data.table always shows the class but it doesn't mean that it should work for both.